# NoAlertPresentException Error when trying to handle popup Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to accept a popup on the Facebook website (before being logged in), asking me whether I accept the cookies or not (see image below). However, I keep getting the Exception saying there's no popup/alert on the page and I'm not sure why.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

obj = browser.switch_to_alert()
obj.accept()
```

Gives me the following error:

```
obj = browser.switch_to_alert()

selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message:
```

I've also tried using time.sleep(5) to let the popup appear but get the same result.

Comment: What is `br = mechanize.Browser()`? Some kind of a browser? Is it a requirement to use it?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that. I was playing around with mechanize but it's not relevant here. I've edited